# Last element in XML Tags?

Tags: xml

```
<Object ID="320">
  <Document Name="A" />
  <Document Name="B" />
  <Document Name="C" />
  <Document Name="D" />
  <book>1</book>
  <book>2</book>
  <book>8</book>
</Object>
```

FOR This XML structure I want to reach last index of Name?

```
 Name="D"
```

How can I do?

Comment: Ummm, take the XML, parse it, use traversal methods and locate the last element? Are you doing this programmatically or something?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="Object">
    <xsl:value-of select="descendant::Document[last()]"/>
</xsl:template>
```